# Find leap years

Tags: php, for-loop

I am working with a php code, to start out i am using the for statment.

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
```

Now i understand that $i=0 counts from 0 and $i < $4 means count from 0 to below 4.

What i am trying to achieve is add multiple for statements rather than using multiple php codes.

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
for($i=4; $i<8; $i++)
for($i=8; $i<12; $i++)
for($i=12; $i<16; $i++)
```

.......etc so that it lists all the results.

```
<?php
$day = "";
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $day =  date("d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 29, date("Y")+$i));
    if($day == 29)
    {
        $year = date("Y")+$i;
        break;
    }
}
echo "<p>The next leap year is 29th February $year</p>";    
?>
```

echoed result will be:

The next leap year is 29th February 2016

The next leap year is 29th February 2020

Comment: What exactly is the problem here ?

Comment: _What i am trying to achieve is add multiple for statements rather than using multiple php codes_ Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Phas1c Use a single for statement with `for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++)`

Comment: This is a prime example of either the OP asking the wrong question or all of the answers answering the wrong question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not like this?

```
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<16; $i++)
    {
        $day = date("d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 29, date("Y")+$i));
        if($day == 29)
        {
            $year = date("Y")+$i;
            echo "<p>The next leap year is 29th February $year</p><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check the leap year with [`date("L")`](http://php.net/date)

```
$yearsToCheck = range(2013, 2020);

foreach ($yearsToCheck as $year) {
    $isLeapYear = (bool) date('L', strtotime("$year-01-01"));
    printf(
        '%d %s a leap year%s',
        $year,
        $isLeapYear ? 'is' : 'is not',
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
2013 is not a leap year
2014 is not a leap year
2015 is not a leap year
2016 is a leap year
2017 is not a leap year
2018 is not a leap year
2019 is not a leap year
2020 is a leap year
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [conditions for a leap year](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html) and just check the years. Use a single statement for this!

```
function is_leap_year($year)
{
   return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)));
}
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, there are too many unnecessary braces. Here's an improved version (without these extra braces): `return $year % 4 == 0 && ($year % 100 != 0 || $year % 400 == 0);`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes to make this kind of thing quick and simple:-

```
$datetime = new \DateTime("2013/01/01");
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1Y');
$period = new \DatePeriod($datetime, $interval, 20);
foreach($period as $date){
    if((bool)$date->format('L')){
        echo $date->format('Y') . " is a Leap Year</br>\n";
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
2016 is a Leap Year
2020 is a Leap Year
2024 is a Leap Year
2028 is a Leap Year
2032 is a Leap Year
```

You could make a function of this to facilitate re-use:-

```
/**
 * @param int $numberOfYears
 * @return array
 */
function getLeapYears($numberOfYears = 10){
    $result = array();
    $datetime = new \DateTime();
    $interval = new \DateInterval("P1Y");
    $period = new \DatePeriod($datetime, $interval, $numberOfYears);
    foreach($period as $date){
        if((bool)$date->format('L')){
            $result[] = $date->format('Y');
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Or test if a given year is a leap year:-

```
function isLeapYear($year)
{
    return (bool)\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', $year)->format('L');
}
```